# Is there a maximum length for a code block/Why all the links instead of code?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm excitedly working-up an answer to this question:
[Emulate an Intel 8086 CPU](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/emulate-an-intel-8086-cpu) . But even though there are several answers, there's no smorgasboard of goodies to steal from like many other older questions.

Should I (May I) prod the answerers to *cough up the code*?

And, Is there a maximum length for code blocks in answers? Would I be asking the impossible for some?

Comment: In the same way that Stack Exchange has a partnership with imgur to host all the images (click the Image toolbar icon and upload a picture---you'll know what I mean), I think Stack Exchange should have a partnership with GitHub to have a Gist-like thing for posting piles of code. It would be useful for the Code Review site, and maybe Stack Overflow and this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum length [was recently increased](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12956/62131). It's now 65536 characters, which should be long enough to post quite a substantial amount of code.

Answer (score 2):

The is a maximum length limit for posts (questions and answers). I believe that it is around 32k characters. That necessarily imposes a a upper limit on how much code you can post, though I find that I am able to write some quite [extensive](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/337/78) things inside that limit.