# Should we increase our post character limit to allow substantial stack snippets?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Calvin's Hobbies posted on Mother Meta about increasing the character limit for posts across the Stack Exchange network. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263792/258647) shows that it is possible to increase the limit from the standard 30,000 characters for individual SE sites, and this has already been doubled for Code Review.

To allow questions to have both a comprehensive spec and description, plus a substantial Stack Snippet, should we increase the character limit for PPCG? Would doubling the limit work for us too, or is there a reason to have more still?

Examples where both spec golfing and controller golfing were required due to the 30,000 character limit:

- [Red vs. Blue - Pixel Team Battlebots](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48353/26997) (29721 characters)
- [Block Building Bot Flocks!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50690/26997) (29977 characters)

---

[*Or should we change it to a smaller limit...?*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24299617#24299617)

Comment: I say "doubled", but actually for Code Review it has been [more than doubled](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101038/i-made-an-implementation-of-stddeque-in-my-own-way#comment184710_101038), to the nice round number 65,536.

Comment: Why not just host the JS (+HTML) externally? It solves the problem of having massive scrollbars on the code snippets too.

Comment: @grc If necessary I'll link to a jsfiddle but I really like the idea of a self contained question which runs the challenge/example/answer validator directly in the same page.

Comment: It's not something I'd recommend spending time and effort on, but if increasing the limit is just a matter of changing a parameter, why not...?

Comment: @grc as for the scrollbars, see Calvin's Hobbies' [Red vs Blue](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48353/red-vs-blue-pixel-team-battlebots) where the code is all put on one line. This gives only a horizontal scrollbar and no wall of text in a question for which the code is not intended to be read (it's still available in readable form externally for anyone wishing to read it).

Comment: I mean `<script src="external.js"></script>` in the code snippet - it's still run on the page.

Comment: @grc I had misunderstood. That's a good point. I'd still rather not depend on the persistence of external sources, but hopefully we'll see arguments for both sides in the answers.

Comment: @trichoplax Is that limit inclusive? Also, it's for questions *and* answers?

Comment: @mbomb007 if by inclusive you mean the maximum number of characters is 30,000 rather than 29,999 then yes I believe it is inclusive (although I don't have a source for that).

Comment: @mbomb007 I *think* the same maximum applies to both questions and answers. It appears that there is just a single limit parameter from the [comment on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101038/i-made-an-implementation-of-stddeque-in-my-own-way#comment184668_101038) but I don't know for certain. If you feel strongly either that they should or should not be the same length, you could post an answer here mentioning both questions and answers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I increased the limit to 65536 to match Code Review. There's an [auto flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203062/1438) for very long posts, so a moderator will have an opportunity to delete or edit unnecessarily long posts. As a rule, giant posts are not good for a site. But if someone really needs to post extremely long code, they can.

Comment: Thanks very much for doing this! Since we encourage people to "sandbox" challenges on meta before posting to main, would you be happy to also increase the post limit on meta (which is currently still 30000), or should this be a new feature request?

Answer (score 39):

### Yes.

The post character limit should be doubled to the same length as Code Review's.

The two most common reasons for the character limit on other Stack Exchange sites (people posting logs, or their entire source code for people to read through) are invalid when applied to PPCG. There won't be anyone posting logs on a PPCG question for obvious reasons. And though people may post the entire source code of a Stack Snippet, the reader is not expected to read through the code.

My hopes are that increasing the character limit will result in even more ambitious challenges utilising Stack Snippets in creative ways.

Comment: [An example of an answer split into two posts to allow lengthy C++ code to fit](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53966/20283)

Answer (score -10):

## No.

I feel that this really goes against the spirit of this website. Programming Puzzles and **Code Golf**, and all. If anything, I say to reduce the post limit.

Comment: Do you want questions and answers to be more limited in length regardless of whether they are golf posts?

Comment: Please golf your answer. I see unnecessary whitespace at the very least.

Comment: #No<LF>Against site spirit.Reduce post limit.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Your comment with code didn't use code formatting. Please use `\`#No<LF>Against site spirit.Reduce post limit.\`` the next time you comment with code.

Comment: Golf many bytes: `Programming Puzzles and **Code Golf**,` -> `PP**CG**`.