# How long can a challenge specification be?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Recently I had the idea to create a KotH challenge based on a card game (played with regular 52 cards). I then began drafting the rules of the game and the interface method.

The thing is, I was taken aback by how lengthy the specification of the challenge is. The Markdown file that contains my draft is more than 8kB, and I'm not even finished yet.

I know that KotH specifications are longer than those of regular challenges, but I would like to avoid them being *too* long.

So, these are the question I would like to ask:

- **How long can a challenge specification be (depending on the type of challenge)?**
- **Are there general tips to reduce the length of a challenge specification (especially KotH)?** Note that the game in question has many variations and optional rules, so I need to crearly define which rules we use.

Comment: I believe there is a hard limit at 30,000 characters for posts (challenges and answers) in most of the site.  I think we may have extended the maximum length for answers, but I do not know if the same applies to questions.   I would recommend researching that, as it sounds like there is a very good possibility that you will exceed the 30,000 character limit.  I would recommend being more brief, while trying to retain a maximum of clarity, if you discover that 30,000 characters is still the limit for this site.

Comment: If you find a challenge becoming longer than you'd like remove fluff and unneeded information, only specify the necessary and be more brief in how you explain things. Also don't overuse too much markdown.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176447) on mother meta talks about the limit.

Comment: @Gryphon 60000 is the limit for questions/answers in the main site, but in meta (so sandbox too) the limit is 30000

Comment: @dzaima , I thought I remembered coming across something talking about increasing the limit for answers, but I wasn't sure if it applied to questions, or if it ever happened.

Comment: @NathanShiranini, because 30,000 characters is the sandbox limit, I would still recommend reducing your question below that, as sandbox feedback is extremely important for the success of most KoTHs.

Comment: Main limit is [65536](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12956/65836), which is `2 ^ 16`.

Answer (score 3):

### [A Challenge Spec can be up to 65536 characters in length.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12956/65836)

Thanks to @StepHen for that number.

However, despite this, a maximum of ~30,000 characters (closer to 33,000) is required for the sandbox, which is heavily recommended for questions.  Therefore, I would recommend cutting a challenge down to 30,000 characters to allow posting in the sandbox.

Now for some tips on cutting challenges down to size.

### Don't over explain.

When I am trying to make my challenges more brief, I find it easiest to remove sections that reexplain sections.  For example, if I explain a rule using a bullet point, I tend to reexplain it later using an example.  Getting rid of unnecessary examples helps a lot, and although retaining test cases is a good idea, examples that illustrate simple steps are often unnecessary.

### Make the challenge simpler.

If all else fails to cut your spec down to a reasonable size, sometimes removing cumbersome rules that require paragraphs of explanation will do the trick.  As you are asking specifically about a KoTH, golfing your controller may also help (if you are including it in you spec as code, and not just a link).  Some excessively complex rules can make a challenge less fun, as well as give it a much longer spec.  Remember, nobody wants to read a 50,000 character wall of text that just explains a bunch of boring, obscure rules designed to cover every possible edge case.  If you need to explain that an edge case is not allowed, you can even do it in a comment on your question, if the explanation is making your spec to cumbersome.

Comment: I definitely agree with simplifying the challenge itself, rather than just writing a shorter spec to describe it. Finding the balance where a KotH is just simple enough without becoming uninteresting is difficult, but well worth it.

Comment: Thank you for your vote of confidence in my reasoning, @trichoplax.