# Would I mind you if I paste long TIO url for Pxem?

Tags: discussion

I am a Pxem user; I have answered some in Pxem. Since tio.run does not provide Pxem, I am posting online demo, with my interpreter, [like this](https://tio.run/##nRhtV9pI9/v@imE2wAwQAoitZRxdRdtlV6mrbrcVqCdCkGhIgAQFgf71PvdOEgzW5@zL6SkzuXPnvr@NPdMffP@ZDIJg5NcM49YOBtObYtcbGh9@1S9HpvXefHyyXGM0s4bFkefbM9sfGjeOd2MMTTuE28VKcWi76@OffCsgujUV06Hp35NSqVIR1mzkTQJyUr8@ODmRdcGC@cgit1bQ9dx@JqO@gOvQdHt8z@hZD4Y7dRxS2cuUM5no8tnB5a@SaizCI/ooJqCOuLbAJV9bhRt9RWO2fzYbn68vLo9kpVTaioFnHy8an0@@XNc/np8f1y9lWbSI7hKqLQ4PLn69/nR8ftH42KwBGdLJZBZEaeURpaXAj/yhWK3vXL12xRpOHTOwiD/AC94ogN2jN@n5I8cOhOnYpk/0W5LVFuU81X6hq6zM4poVzT9PTuqnR7KmWIDSyLAn/IHdDxTzHkHECGB1Bx7RfuaUSFJG1kxB/IEFNgw8j3hOby@DXrADUubCejAdQlOkbzq@RZfLV9BJEl9JoHBmS9/qkaxvzIy5IXz4eTKyiu8T6SyXoLKiBDg/sAVNwALOg3z3ToALR7ZjMc76siS6pm8BhzIltktYP8dJH7whLN/sCtP3reGNM0fHe@DzA5foD8G0vAwmRK/7pFSubFW337zdeUeyrbab62SXtxNrRIpL8/GeZA@PPzSaCweY9GT1jQDrstHEdoM@yY7OvI9u025cd@v@xcOn/nvreHL@@Nfs8/zL05V5EFwOT3tHeT2lpdPZ5X9grZUkrbco0UqEdmSbUjCJ4z1aE@aHIjCa7tKCVuKc0DYVVIAhsyo0GKWFiwKtUS5Q9L70JaWi702YgIh3bNci/b2S4Au7z2KAvytLXOEB0EdL1jOZvpQ9vjhmXCiWpN7yO2JlgdcJYqnTxwF6ItyfsD5HduIl4fAECSlnlsRqtWbzIwPFIbxywnwOAMRY9aduN7A9l5ywrpK9mwJ5uR@Y3fuWk893ZDeBBFcQx@GLyGPUiWzggO6OrvMYDv8iGnq5EwkCdlitssoT@gPxIHxU8NE4JEKtIx33QEE3L43W42z@1DF0wzTQAu5uKWJOiyY5rJJiiECXtGtCRENs03VwKzzwNQupmB1jn5JfQDQ3D@RqoCeS9JRORs/IZFIuj2wZQvhiKl29LELJ3L1p0r3KB5EooRDk0fBI0XxVlpe6hMJRM5IHMJT73H9BMnY7xKiI7J72222sfXGK0iVrkdDMRHcCUsFKBJSWsRdMWcIFglTrU9wNAJD1c2Cyked2/YdJ0DFyzNwt87zRykPm6eF3hYN/rFkgVsbIWAAZ4UOBWPm7ZQH/o6MB7AageGDkUilTrBa@TBmtvhV5Q5hoFPu6Y@QNB6g23@vAhpngexCgC4Zqea4PAgBwgEBjaOhwXIZdLItYlSFJX6i5taFmdnHWsvOljtTAr/m8GEn41iuQFKNvEMCZDDBfhCA5CkN3euMHE6aVCltc9CzHgoZx1tJ1uyNCxeDiV4e0vpJOHu93jQVcYVQBNFqgGZKhhZDk3xLQkIJvLGxdVl7g/p@bTnRD8SRrpv@Y47PgsRUh9MHjWhp3gMhIaUlKIRrXKF94aDuoniMxk1rzvSBzqYXuEgkhkqKMOOJ7mEizXTnni2s5g8tzMZfXYrVhbYhcZrTzxv4sP6@B0/dnOqwpWHOwpmFNz2vQ3F7X67h5tMASdAcheLdri7t8PqxCgHbXweyI@yOkWjGnGUY2BBhgDrChYWDTRMlzxhnLcGHcwjeBwUvcQH9UeWBfQyb0rUkw7IDdjQxUTkMEIk5oAIUVAg74Qp2YCFypbQ@32OWwZffX84DqylnMYVbi2eUy/O4B6YkVTCcudp6QSx4JmL1ezFXHb/8miL9T@A1jTfzd1hDQsx9iQFoheDEB3yjmjL8u3zOagQoI5ngh2bodh2X5onUvIXkgweM@OAj7YBamhCCuPFk09HJ9dd0yLHbIF/eQdUCmI@EH@wH66xAoHu4iVByCy2BTOIwQYPOCOIoODLjq8z0CRY4LSG2/O7FHgYwExe5nWb1vtAgNbALjqPpMNrkzdsRRn8LvjHfkkZIJRNtscKH5U79vtMff1gcEDvbKiaPfn4@UNs8nlxsnyBSVfz7/zM754lwCmpJE1yPXk/ME0pTVo57A9PIuDBD13cr2G75fr2E/XaN9QFpggan7zSgaSHbqiqmLw8cz0Wi3brH7WqmmJ3X5E5nBrXoCdsBO46Z0cANTeg1S9vS1frS@MWLxCJMCg/Ip@wy/iXMvHCNeP3RZozAuHBWcZ5zFWAISzF2O5d4GAzbmKoIa0HAau9IRDYifKWNHMqrb40KjUOb8G22V9Hcdun@Ur@7Uqts49KzZ2CDDGfuwyfuanRbqhavCF744lbR4XSNNL8D6ZN1aEyrqEvDFFbBVM0847FXfhk7Z3uE3E8u8x4pXh1pbbW1td7B2XslqVa9Hl0MU7PRsJ7xXrkJ3q0u5hR01RIL3U2C7U0us0PYhdn23uoOIe9tvOVdgJcMz95AB/yK/EFbXAVmgM8UZu8p9SerYTRj/jF1uGsBPHH7eSIAHcMtd4RNXtRZMX4Jsv5MqpMEJd2CLT5i8hUZHqAVHR9zchd93ut6Rn5IOmCRY4WYCrzjPdeaZDMiEs9UBo8VJjcCWohqYACqpeQ4jZsOZj8@JBuSgDAFGCkgk5J@xPwrjkCPkMo@wy@IPFVphgEXAP3bHiYvzf3FxL3nxaS0UC6/GckXirxGDhCUGWCU3LT8Mj@9xsB@AyxAled5DzyRRoi6JeOIeisqGx1SJamDdzUMtYpg6INdduIT1kPPQcVIhoUefmak2hLx@U@EDkuZf5C82psYaBXIMWAOKjmi7pX29UWts@E41rg2KuRcUsZONo3rwWxQtTBkexkRHrTKKF61GrqyJl1pHzHjP2R8bTs0xxpwnuUI3/Ic006/STAPNtKKJrf37@@bB6bH8qf6xeXncvJTf43eQpg7oMnpdkz78uObQgjHrBcZjl@hdqKeJk4ja820sDJYbvIby4/W1rn2w7/qNnbjy3x7QzXM1tME8CHMU/tFGvydld1Iox2PWV1V1c6TNirk212CoapdxzOArCg8VbMlSDUN6l6i/Kk0xq70hTh4AnPwAfBazVyV6s7qBgCOHD@ceGdm9ghXYQ6sw6o6mhQf/SfTMwOJJNat/r2Zg2g7R3WolVgeUYMX2Yqe9QmXaZSP7/HbSK@Xq2@rO1pvqDrwy4DUDVlEDaTiAmuHb7N/bGV9koZ1wofigi4cdGiOMZTuL68fzC5nNxsMa5roNk5WNQwK@dni3ZXfk@s8b7XbaowUb0qt5nt4uSVmOZPUJXb/dx/CWGxPadmHAiI67La3UCXXDMSuasGMkiIQB0f3v/wM).

The problem is: code for the interpreter is long; so does the url. I have never been critized about that, but would I mind you if I keep submitting so?

Comment: So long as it isn't [longer than 65536 characters](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12956/66833), it's no problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a problem at all, and others have done so before.